# Sklearn NotFittedError: This LinearRegression instance is not fitted yet

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying a simple linear regression and I have tried this code:

```
x1=data.iloc[:, 9].values
y1=data.iloc[:,1].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
seed=7
x1_train,x1_test,y1_train,y1_test= 
train_test_split(x1,y1,test_size=0.15,random_state=seed)

x1_train=nm.reshape(nm.array(x1_train),(-1,1))

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lireg=LinearRegression()
model1=LinearRegression().fit(x1_train,y1_train)

y_pred=lireg.predict(x1_test)
```

> NotFittedError: This LinearRegression instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method

Please help

Comment: try "y_pred=model1.predict(x1_test)"

Comment: Thanks a lot James. It worked. An explanation to why my code didn't work would be helpful to understand the difference.

Comment: let me know if my answer helps.

Comment: "lireg" had never fit anything, so it could not predict anything. On the other hand, "model1" *had* fit some data, so it could predict some values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the **explanation why you got this error**. Let's have a look at the following lines:

```
lireg=LinearRegression()
model1=LinearRegression().fit(x1_train,y1_train)
y_pred=lireg.predict(x1_test)
```

**What happens here?**

- You initialise 2 `LinearRegression` models named: `lireg` and `model1`
- For the `lireg` you DO NOT call `.fit` but for `model1` you do.
- `y_pred=lireg.predict(x1_test)` throws the error because you try to `.predict` using `lireg`, but `lireg` is not trained / fitted.

---

**You just need this:**

**Way 1:**

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

lireg=LinearRegression() # initialize the model
lireg.fit(x1_train,y1_train) # fit he model
y_pred=lireg.predict(x1_test) # now predict
```

**Way 2:**

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

lireg=LinearRegression().fit(x1_train,y1_train) # initialize & fit the model
y_pred=lireg.predict(x1_test) # now predict
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really explains and helps a lot.